# Edit the email wordpress sends

Tags: html, wordpress, email

I have an Time Entry email layout on a page that the user logs in and will submit work time. When I get the email to send it comes in like this

`{“action”:”ls_time_entry”,”origin”:”174″,”dateEntry”:””,”startTime”:””,”endTime”:””,”Staff”:”Y292DA7423A6E933″,”Matter”:”A6D67A7928CF5527″,”Discount_Note”:””,”Description”:””}`

How do I get it to display like this or at least close to this:

```
Date:
Start Time:
End Time:
Staff:
Matter:
Discount Note:
Description:
```

Comment: is there a way we can see the code that sends the email ?

Comment: Here is a link to the code.

https://pastebin.com/SM0vCzf5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, replace the line 34 :

```
$message = $json;
```

with

```
$message = "Date: ".$_POST['dateEntry']." Start Time: ".$_POST['startTime']. " End Time: ".$_POST['endTime']." Staff: ".$_POST['Staff']." Matter: ".$_POST['Matter']." Discount Note: ".$_POST['Discount_Note']." Description: ".$_POST['Description'];
```

the idea is to use $_POST to get individual values instead of the JSON form

you may add line retur using **br** or **/n** (if br doesn't work)

```
$message = "Date: ".$_POST['dateEntry']."<br/>Start Time: ".$_POST['startTime']. "<br/>End Time: ".$_POST['endTime']."<br/>Staff: ".$_POST['Staff']."<br/>Matter: ".$_POST['Matter']."<br/>Discount Note: ".$_POST['Discount_Note']."<br/>Description: ".$_POST['Description'];
```

or

```
$message = "Date: ".$_POST['dateEntry']."\nStart Time: ".$_POST['startTime']. "\nEnd Time: ".$_POST['endTime']."\nStaff: ".$_POST['Staff']."\nMatter: ".$_POST['Matter']."\nDiscount Note: ".$_POST['Discount_Note']."\nDescription: ".$_POST['Description'];
```

Comment: Thanks. I sent the email and it showed up like this in my inbox:
`Date: 09/22/2017 Start Time: 04:07PM End Time: 04:07PM Staff: Y292DA7423A6E933 Matter: A6D67A7928CF5527 Discount Note: Test DN Description: Description`

Is there a way to move each field to a new line?

Comment: you may add  **br** tag between each field like this :
.'<br/>'.
it should do the stuff if it's configured to show html email

Comment: or add '\n' at the end of each filed

Comment: Is there a way to calculate the Difference for the start and end times here as well?

Comment: yes you can, but you need first to transform both date on seconds, then do the difference, you should use the **mktime** function. read more here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

Comment: I'm not sure why it wasn't showing up for you, but I've now [moved this conversation to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155289/discussion-on-answer-by-temani-afif-edit-the-email-wordpress-sends). Once the issue is resolved, please consider updating the answer with any relevant code. Thanks!

Comment: @CodyGray the answer no more need update but we was talking about smething else he wanted and i wasn't getting the chat to be able to discuss about this outside, but we found a solution :)